# How python can help me to make my website?

Tags: python, html

i want to develop a website in Python. Can someone tell me how I can do this. currently I am using ASP.NET MVC for web development.

I want to make just the Hello world sample. It should print dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using string Templates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import string

s=string.Template("""
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"

        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>$text</p>
</body>
</html>
""")

s.substitute(text='Hello World')
```

Now, store the output into a file and open it in a browser...

For more serious development, have a look at [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)